# Converting data to string

Tags: php, laravel, data-processing

I need to convert data, like this:

```
{
    "action": "PushEvent",
    "commits_count": 5,
    "repository": {"name":"example-repo"}
}
```

To a string, like this: User pushed 5 commits to example-repo

The problem is, I have very high amount of action types to support. What would be the best solution to this problem and where should I put the code (Laravel)?

Comment: Does the data look always the way you describe or can the structure change? Is the data coming from a model or is it something else?

Comment: Action and repository are constant, there can be also type sometimes (for example create, delete, modify). Data is coming from Activity model, which gets it from cache/GitHub's API

Comment: you need to convert this at php side or js side?

Comment: I don't have any restrictions, I'm looking for the best way to do it. I'm going to send notifications in the future so I think php side will be the best option

Comment: Do you make use of translation?

Comment: I don't. (additional chars because comments was too short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is the way to go, example:

```
$source = '{
    "action": "PushEvent",
    "commits_count": 5,
    "repository": {"name":"example-repo"}
}';

$actions = ['PushEvent' => 'pushed'];

$result = json_decode($source, true);

var_dump(sprintf('User %s %d commits to %s', $actions[$result['action']], $result['commits_count'], $result['repository']['name']));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you best put it into the `Activity` model (or a trait, if you want to keep the model clean). For the method itself, you won't have much other options than implementing each action individually. Maybe you can combine multiple actions when you use `switch-case`, but the hardest part will probably be translating the action into a verb.

Alternatively, you could also put it into a blade component. This would make sense if you plan on having your notifications look nice, e.g. if you look at the following HTML

```
<span class="activity">
    <span class="activity-user">User</span> pushed
    <span class="activity-count">5</span> commits to
    <span class="activity-repository">
       <a href="/path/to/example-repo">example-repo</a>
    </span>.
</span>
```

you'll notice that you can't just create the same afterwards if you compile your activity into a plain text sentence.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try something like this

```
<?php

function convert_multi_array($glue, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (@is_array($value))
        {
            $arr[$key] = convert_multi_array ($glue, $arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    return implode($glue, $arr);
}

$json_data = <<<END_OF_JSON
{
    "action": "PushEvent",
    "commits_count": 5,
    "repository": {"name":"example-repo"}
}
END_OF_JSON;

$array_data = json_decode($json_data, true);

$string_data = convert_multi_array(',', $array_data);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_data);
print_r($array_data);
echo($string_data);
die();
```